# Using ARC and UITableViewController is throwing Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, automatic-ref-counting

I cannot seem to figure out what to do to resolve this error that I am receiving.  I click on a cell which pops a new UITableViewController onto the stack.  Once I hit the back button on the Navigation UI when in this controller I receive this error in the debugger but there doesn't seem to be any issue with the app as it doesn't crash or hang and still works fine.

An instance 0x79a8400 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
 (
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0x738c010>
)

Code is below and I am using similar code on other UITableViewControllers but not receiving the error.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    pull = [[PullToRefreshView alloc] initWithScrollView:(UIScrollView *) self.tableView];
    [pull setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView addSubview:pull];
    [tableView.dataSource self];
    [tableView.delegate self];

    NSString *isAuthenticated = [[NSString alloc] init];
    isAuthenticated = [self retrieveUserToken:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"email"]];
    NSNumber *categorySelected = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
    categorySelected = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"category_id"];
    if (![isAuthenticated length])
    {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         return;
    }else if (categorySelected ==nil) 
    {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         return;
    }

         [self getTableViewData];
    }

 - (void)viewDidUnload
 {
     [self setTableView:nil];
     pull = nil;
     [super viewDidUnload];
     // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }

 - (NSString *)retrieveUserToken:(NSString *)user
 {
     NSError *error = nil;
     NSString *username = user;
     return [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:username  andServiceName:@"app" error:&error];
 }

 - (void)getTableViewData 
 {
     URLSingleton *urls = [[URLSingleton alloc] init];
     responseData = [NSMutableData data];
     NSNumber *categoryID = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
     categoryID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"category_id"];

     NSString *urlComplete = [[NSString alloc] init];
     urlComplete = [urls getEvent:categoryID];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlComplete]];
     NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
     [connection start];
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
 {
     return categories.count;
 }  

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                         initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                         reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

     cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     cell.textLabel.text = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     return cell;
 }

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
 {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self.tableView reloadData]; 
 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 {
     [responseData setLength:0];
 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
     [responseData appendData:data];
 }

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
     [pull finishedLoading];
     [alert show];
 }

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
     NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
     NSArray *response = [dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
     NSArray *responseID = [dictionary valueForKey:@"id"];

     categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:response];
     eventID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:responseID];
     [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
     [pull finishedLoading];
 } 

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

     UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
     int i = 0;
     for(NSString *name in categories)
     {
         if ([name isEqualToString:cellText]) 
         {
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[eventID objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"event_id"];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:cellText forKey:@"event_name"];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
         }
         i++;
     }

     [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

     if(checkedIndexPath) {
         UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [self.tableView
                                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:checkedIndexPath];
         uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     }
      UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
      checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
  }

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {

     URLSingleton *urls = [URLSingleton sharedInstance];
     NSNumber *event = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
     if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
     {  
         UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
         NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
         int i = 0;
         for(NSString *name in categories)
         {
             if ([name isEqualToString:cellText]) 
             {
                 event = [eventID objectAtIndex:i];
                 [eventID removeObjectAtIndex:i];
             }
             i++;
         }

         NSString *reqURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[urls deleteEvent:[event stringValue]]];
         NSURLRequest *delReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqURL]]; 
         NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
         NSError *err = nil; 
         NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:delReq returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
         NSString *reply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         SBJsonParser *parser = [SBJsonParser new];
         id content = [reply JSONValue];
         if(!content){
              NSLog(@"%@", parser.errorTrace);
             [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
             return;
         }
         NSNumber *status = [content valueForKey:@"success"];
         NSNumber *one = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:1];
         if ([status isEqualToNumber:one])
         {
              [categories removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
              [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
         }else 
         {
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alert show];
         }

     }
 }

 - (void)pullToRefreshViewShouldRefresh:(PullToRefreshView *)view;
 {
     NSString *isAuthenticated = [[NSString alloc] init];
     isAuthenticated = [self retrieveUserToken:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"email"]];
     NSNumber *categorySelected = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
     categorySelected = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"category_id"];
     if (![isAuthenticated length])
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         return;
     }else if (categorySelected ==nil) 
     {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         return;
     }
      [self getTableViewData];
 }

 - (IBAction)createEvent:(id)sender 
 {
     NSString *isAuthenticated = [[NSString alloc] init];
     isAuthenticated = [self retrieveUserToken:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"email"]];
     NSNumber *categorySelected = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
     categorySelected = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"category_id"];
     if (![isAuthenticated length])
     {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         return;
     }else if (categorySelected == nil) 
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Alert" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         return;
     }
     AddEventViewController *aevc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddEventViewController"];
     [self.navigationController popToViewController:aevc animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: I commented out the PullToRefreshView function calls and the error went away.  I looked at that code and there is an observer being set and there is also a -(void) dealloc method to remove the observer so I am not sure if that isn't being called or what is happening.

Comment: Fixed it by adding the following dealloc method


     - (void)dealloc 
     {
         [self.tableView removeObserver:pull forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"];
     }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following method

```
- (void)dealloc
{ 
    [self.tableView removeObserver:pull forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"];
}
```

Comment: i have the exact same bug ,and that method is already in my PullToRefreshView class. Any thoughts on why that could be?

Comment: You need to add the removeObserver to your tableview in it's controllers dealloc method